# Sorting CSV with record delimiter that is not a newline or zero byte

Tags: sorting, csv, awk

My CSV looks something like this:

```
"212314334","a sentence with new line in it \n
this is the next line","kajdfad","213",ENDOFLINE\r\n
"212314333","another sentence with new line in it \r\n
this is the next line","kawad","21453",ENDOFLINE\r\n
```

So there could be newlines in the middle of a record. There could also be non-printable characters in the file. The record delimiter is `,ENDOFLINE\r\n`.

Linux `sort` has record delimiter that is either newline or a zero-byte so I could not use it.

I tried using `awk` with `RS`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {RS="ENDOFLINE\r\n"} {print }' myFile | sort -t $',' -k 1
```

But it looks like sort is still using newline as a delimiter, because it is splitting records in the middle.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Edit with possible solution a colleague suggested:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {RS="END\r\n";i=0;} {array[i]=$2","$0"END\r"; i=i+1}END {n = asort(array, dest);for (i=1; i<=n; i++) dest[i] = substr(dest[i], index(dest[i], $1)) ; for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print dest[i]}
```

This is not exactly like the example I gave. The sorting here is done based on the second feild, which is attached as first field for the sorting and then removed.

Comment: it is not very clear what is your ultimate goal. Could you clarify?

Comment: You show your sample input as ending each line with `ENDOFLINE\n` but then in your awk script you set your RS to `ENDOFLINE\r\n` (i.e. you stick a `\r` in the middle). Seems like that could be a problem. Does your file contain `\r`s? If so where are they and would they make a better RS?

Comment: @fedorqui my goal is to sort the records by one of the columns (the first one, in the example I gave)

Comment: @Ed Morton I tried to simplify the problem and accidentally dropped the /r. It is part of the record delimiter.

Comment: OK and where does it appear? Update your sample input and expected output to reflect reality.

Comment: @Ed Morton fixed the example. Just to make things clearer - \r\n can appear also in the middle of the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: There were some embarrassing errors in the original code that were pointed out to me in the comments. This should fix them.

The trouble is that `sort` no longer knows about the splitting that `awk` did because `awk`'s output is unchanged from the input. My suggestion is to do the whole thing in `awk`;

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { RS = "ENDOFLINE\r\n" } { lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 RT } END { n = asorti(lines, keys); for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { printf("%s", lines[keys[i]]) } }'
```

The awk code is

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -F, -f

BEGIN {
  RS = "ENDOFLINE\r\n"
}
{
  lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 RT     # remember lines by first field in an associative
                                  # array; append lines with duplicate keys.
}
END {
  n = asorti(lines, keys)         # sort keys; sorted keys end up in the array
                                  # named keys with indices from 1 to n
  for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {       # then walk through the sorted keys
    printf("%s", lines[keys[i]])  # and print the lines.
  }
}
```

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1`, indistinguishable in some fonts. More importantly though, `for(l in lines)` will access the keys in the order they are stored in the internal hash table, not the order in which you just sorted them. Even more importantly, `asort()` sorts by array contents, not by indices  (that's for `asorti()`). And most importantly, this solution assumes that the `$1` values are unique which there's no indication they are and so will delete any initial entries with duplicate `$1` values.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh boy, that was embarrassing. Code update should fix all that. I have no excuse.

Comment: It will still delete any lines with duplicate $1s and still print the lines in a random order after sorting courtesy of `in`.

Comment: Now you're down to just the random output order - to fix that, get rid of your explicit population of `keys[]` as you need to use  `asorti(lines,keys)` to create a 2nd array of the indices and then write your loop as `for (k=1;k in keys;k++)`. And then it's time for some coffee :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I was just reading up on that. Odd that I never ran into that problem. Is it possible that this coincidentally always works with GNU awk? I'm not suggesting it's something to depend upon, but it might explain why I never ran into this as a problem. I may change the code again to incorporate your approach once I read the asorti docs some more, by the way.

Comment: The `in` operator CAN (and often does for small input sets) co-incidentally loop through the array indices in the order you want even though it's actually printing in the order the values are stored in the hash table, not alphabetic or numeric or any other useful order of indices. You can force GNU awk to use some other order by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to some specific pre-defined ordering value or even to the name of a function you provide yourself to order the traversal.

Comment: The only thing you need to change now is `lines[$1] $0 RS` to `lines[$1] $0 RT` or you'll end up adding a blank record to the end of the output file.

Comment: @EdMortin: I suppose I might as well, since I'm already using GNU extensions. It's only a problem if the last record doesn't have the terminator, though, in which case I think it's possible you'd want to put it there anyway -- like a newline at the end of a file. I'm not entirely sure about this one.

Comment: Actually, it may not be a problem in this case. It all depends how the `\r`s and `\n`s are really used in the input file. The issue I was imagining is where the last record ends in the terminator but then is followed by a `\r` or `\n` but that may not be the case.

Comment: One other gotcha to consider: array indices are strings therefore asorti() will by default sort by string comparison not numeric even if the indices look like numbers so if the key values are of different lengths you will find that `11` comes before `2`. You can specify a 3rd arg for asorti() to dictate the type of sorting to do (e.g. `"@ind_num_asc"`), but you'd need to strip off the `"`s from the key field to get a numeric sort even with that or all indices will be treated as numeric zero.

Comment: @Wintermute thanks for the answer. I am new to awk and having trouble understanding the line: lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 RT. I assume $0 is the number I want to sort by, but what is $1 and what is the meaning of lines[$1]?

Comment: `$0` is the current record, `$1` is the first field in it (the one you want to sort by). `lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 RT` appends the line plus record terminator to a slot with key `$1` in an associative array `lines` (a hash map, in essence). If the value in the first field appears for the first time, this will be the same as assigning the line to that slot (because `lines[$1]` will be empty), if the key appears several times, the lines will be concatenated in the order they appear.

Comment: If you're new to awk, you may find [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) enlightening. At first, awk scripts look a bit awkward because their control flow is unlike most other programming languages (it is similar to sed). In a nutshell, awk fetches records (lines by default, `ENDOFLINE`-delimited blocks here) from the input file(s) and applies the whole code to each record, which means executing the blocks if their associated condition is true. So the `BEGIN` block is executed only for the first record, `END` for the last, and the one without a condition every time. See link.

Comment: @Wintermute If I understand correctly, lines with the same field will be erased, and I don't want this to happen..

Comment: No, they're not erased. They're pasted together in `lines[field]` in the order in which they appear.

Comment: @Wintermute So if the second field is the same in all records, all the first fields will be in one array cell, and won't be sorted?

Comment: No, the first fields are the keys to the array. All lines with the same first field are concatenated in the array element with that first as its key. If you have two lines `"foo","bar",ENDOFLINE\r\n` and "foo","qux",ENDOFLINE\r\n`, then `lines["foo"]` will be `"foo","bar",ENDOFLINE\r\n"foo","qux",ENDOFLINE\r\n`. The second field doesn't come into it. Did you want to sort by the second field? Then replace `$1` with `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk -F, -vRS="ENDOFLINE/n" '
        {a[NR]=$0}END{x=asort(a);while(++i<=x)printf "%xs",a[i] RT}' file
```

---

This works similar to wintermutes but sort on the content instead of indices.

As you are sorting on $1, and it is sorted from the start, then sorting on the whole line should give the same results.

I am assuming that all the first fields are the same length, as it appears in the question.

Comment: Sorting on the whole line when sorting on $1 is desired will may or may not give the same results depending on whether $1 is always the same number of characters long.

Comment: @EdMorton Just reread what you said,it looks like all OP's first fields are the same, should have put that as an assumption though i suppose.

Comment: It's hard to tell from 2 lines of input. I'd just assumed they're numbers but idk.